# Firebase Authentication on nodejs, how to login a user and use mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, firebase

I just realized I built a web app around a bug.
I use firebase authentication to login the user. Then I use the user-uid from firebase to find the user with the id in mongodb. The connection between firebase and mongodb work but when I close the browser, use a differnt browser or connect to the localserver via phone the user is still logged in. So one user loggs in and every client which is connected to the server is loggd in with the same data unless someone presses "Logout" or the server gets restarted.

I tried to set a persistence with `firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)` but then I get the error `Error: The current environment does not support the specified persistence type.`

Why does the server saves the loggd in user, how can I fix that? :(

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who landed on this by search engines:
I solved this by recoding the login system to a cookie based authentication.
You can use the tutorial by firebase:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies